# Speed up MySQL query that checks duplicates with mismatched values and updates

Tags: mysql

Can i speed up this query to make it faster? right now its taking 51 seconds.

```
UPDATE tbl_user_tmp tut
  INNER JOIN tbl_user_tmp tut1 ON tut.name = tut1.name
  SET tut.image = '1', tut1.image='1'
  WHERE tut.image = 0 AND tut1.image=1 and tut.user = 'user' and tut1.user = 'user'
```

Im trying to find entires with same name and update image if one name has image that equals 0 and another equals 1.

Im not able to put an index on this table because its updated and inserted by users on my site. From what i understand adding index's will slow those queries down. I need it to be quick. This is really the only query i have that is causing an issue. So hope to figure out a way without having to index.

Comment: Do you have index on column `name` ? Have you checked your execution plan? It also depends on the size of a table. You're nesting your query a bit which seems like it might be processing a fair amount of your table. Might that be the case? Please try to count rows having `image in (0,1) and user = 'user'` and compare them with total number of rows.

Comment: How about something like `UPDATE tbl_user_tmp tut SET tut.image = '1' WHERE tut.image = 0 AND tut.user = 'user' and tut.name in (select name from tbl_user_tmp where image = 1 and user = 'user')`? (No way to test it on my side, though...)

Comment: @JanakaBandara, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 1):

This is the query:

```
UPDATE tbl_user_tmp tut INNER JOIN
       tbl_user_tmp tut1
       ON tut.name = tut1.name
    SET tut.image = 1,
        tut1.image = 1
  WHERE tut.image = 0 AND tut1.image = 1 and tut.user = 'user' and tut1.user = 'user';
```

Indexes will help this query.  I would suggest:

```
create index idx_tbl_user_tmp_1 on tbl_user_tmp(image, user, name)
create index idx_tbl_user_tmp_2 on tbl_user_tmp(name, image, user)
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory and write performance is not a concern, the easiest solution is to put indexes on the restricting columns (`name`, `image` and `user`)

Update (in answer to @Bignadad's update): Indexes will slow down `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries. That however might not be noticable on a small scale. If you really need high read *and* write performance than you might have to look at other solutions such as caching or separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer written after your updated version of question.

Putting indexes does indeed slow queries like `UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE` down, but that may not even be noticeable to you. Imagine this: I have a table with around 10mln rows to which people `INSERT` and `UPDATE` every minute and I also have indexes on about 5 columns. This seriously isn't that big of a deal in most cases.

If the performance is really the key you should make separate tables for different value of `image`, if the table is really big try partitioning or simply leave it the way it is.

Since you hadn't given every detail I asked for (execution plan), number of rows etc, this is all I can advise.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1) check that `tbl_user_tmp.name` is an index

2) better yet, if you are going to do something like this often, introduce a compound index for (name, user)

3) having an index should not drastically slow down adding new entries to your table (unless it already has more than 100K entries)

4) try this:

```
update tbl_user_tmp tut1,tbl_user_tmp tut2
    set tut1.image=1
    where tut1.name=tut2.name and tut1.user=tut2.user
    and tut1.image=0 and tut2.image=1;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f03f2/1

5) Do you really need name to identify user? If only "user" field is enough, then drop "name" from the query (joining on strings is supposed to be slow, especially if these strings aren't in the index).